# odds with floating computations

Tags: python, floating-point

Although the topic isn't quite new and relevant, I cannot figure out one thing.

When I use Python 2.7.8 (x86) IDLE on x64 Windows 7, Intel core i5 760, I found that my machine has odds in *multiplying* particular float/double numbers, but not all of them!

```
>>> print 0.01 == 0.1 * 0.1
False
>>> print (1/10.0) ** 2 == 0.01
False
>>> print 0.01 - 0.1 ** 2
-1.73472347598e-18

BUT:
>>> print 1/10.0 * 1/10.0 == 0.01
True
>>> print 0.015 == 0.05 * 0.3
True
>>> print 0.0002 == 0.01 * 0.02
True
>>> print 0.0001 == 0.01 * 0.01
True
... (and so on. Always true.)
```

**(!)** I am not talking about such difficult (for PC and... for me) operations like taking in power, log, exp. I'm talking about multiplying, divison, adding and substracting.

I read [this](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/167402/Indepth_Intermediate_floatingpoint_precision.php) and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/floating_point_comparison.html) to dive deeply. It says that actually using comparisons such like 1.1 == 1.1 can lead to false. In my case, it is not. Thus, my computer rounds this float representations into the same bits represetations.

Using Java 7 with Eclipse compiler gives me the same results. Thus, I can conclude that the result in my case depends only on my machine epsilone (register precision), which is less than 1.734723475976807e-18, but not on compiler and programming environment.

The question is **why my machine fails to compare 0.01 == 0.1 * 0.1 whereas causing no disrepancy with other multiplying examples (I tried a lot to confuse my PC!) ?**

Comment: Because IEEE 754 does not guarantee ultimate precision for arbitrary number of significant digits. Depending on how the result was calculated, it might be "incorrect" by a different fraction.

Comment: `0.1 * 0.1` doesn't happen to round the way you want. The other computations you tried happened to round the way you want. There's nothing deeper to it than that.

Comment: @user2357112, why then 0.0002 == 0.01 * 0.02 leads to true? Isn't that rounded?

Comment: Because that one just happens to round the way you wanted it to. When you tried to produce other examples like `0.01 != 0.1 * 0.1`, you didn't try hard enough. `0.4 * 0.9 != 0.36`. `0.7 * 0.8 != 0.56`. `0.2 * 0.4 != 0.08`. Since the computer is really doing all the math in binary rather than decimal, whether a calculation happens to round the way you want is something you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, as you might have noticed, not always 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 for PC. And I think, when a programmer is writing a code and if he didn't confront with issues about 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 or 0.1 * 0.1 != 0.01, he won't care a lot about all his computational results with floating point numbers unless he detects one. I think in most cases people are used to check 0.1+0.2 == 0.3 instead of 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3 < epsilon.

Comment: @user2357112, I see. Okay, so it turns out that I should always use an epsilon notation to valid floating point results. I didn't think about it till now!.. I'm closing a topic as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014) for the answer to your question. The problem is that all floating point math is like this and is based on the IEEE 754 standard. JavaScript uses 64-bit floating point representation, which is the same as Java's double.

Instead, if you are using this for an actual program, use an *epsilon*, or a very very small number:

```
>>> import math
>>> epsilon = 0.1**5
>>> (math.fabs((0.1 * 0.1) - 0.01) < epsilon)
True
>>>
```